# Outllook addin await Folder.Items.Find() Exception

Tags: c#, dynamic, async-await, outlook-addin

Hello I m trying to search a contact folder  and I m getting an exception any ideas why?

```
string filter = "[Email1Address] = '"+item.Email1Address+ "' or [FullName] = '" + item.FullName + "'";

dynamic matches =  await toFolder.Items.Find(filter);
```

I m getting

```
System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'
```

If I remove the 'await' it works but Outlook freeze for 5 secs and i DONT want that.

Comment: try `Task.Run(() => { matches = toFolder.Items.Find(filter)});`

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to `await` it? Have you done any research on how the `await` and `async` keywords work?

Comment: `await` doesn't make anything run automagically in the background. It *awaits* on already executing Tasks (or any class with a GetAwaiter method) to complete before resuming execution in the next line.

Comment: Ned that what I have done dor now and it works but the method its called many times and It crashes. Daniel yes I have and I know await also makes outlook not to freeze while my addin works.

Answer (score 1):

The error really means what it says - Items.Find is synchronous and you cannot use "await" with a COM method.

Comment: But when I go to with my mouse on top of Find it says awaitable and usage: await Find

Comment: You need to take it up with the VS team :-)